# Как сделать блок как на фото на html с помощью div, без table?

Tags: php, html, css, css3

Как сделать на html следующий блок чтобы картинки были рядом, а текст внизу после каждой картинки, т.е. блок должен выглядеть также как на фотке, только блок должен быть сверстан как div, а не как таблица (table).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: т.е вы сами не пытались что то сделать?

Comment: Пытался, но у меня не получается сделать блоки текста

Answer (score 3):

Как пример, можете так сделать, хотя желательно знать что за картинки у вас будут.... и некоторые детали

```css
.wrapp,.wrapp ul{
width: 100%;
display: inline-block;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.wrapp ul li{
list-style:none;
float:left;
width:15%;
margin:0px 10px 0px 0px;
}
.imagesBox{
width:100%;
text-align:center;
}
.imagesBox img{
width:100px;
height:100px;
}
.wrapp ul li p{
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapp">
<ul>
<li>
<div class="imagesBox"><img src="http://vprazdnik-perm.ru/upload/shop/pos/790_s.jpg"></div>
<p>Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба" </p>
</li>
   <li>
<div class="imagesBox"><img src="http://vprazdnik-perm.ru/upload/shop/pos/790_s.jpg"></div>
<p>Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба" </p>
</li>
   <li>
<div class="imagesBox"><img src="http://vprazdnik-perm.ru/upload/shop/pos/790_s.jpg"></div>
<p>Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба" </p>
</li>
 <li>
<div class="imagesBox"><img src="http://vprazdnik-perm.ru/upload/shop/pos/790_s.jpg"></div>
<p>Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба" </p>
</li>
<li>
<div class="imagesBox"><img src="http://vprazdnik-perm.ru/upload/shop/pos/790_s.jpg"></div>
<p>Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба" </p>
</li>
<li>
<div class="imagesBox"><img src="http://vprazdnik-perm.ru/upload/shop/pos/790_s.jpg"></div>
<p>Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба" </p>
</li>
</ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Это не универсальное решение, мне нужно более универсальное решение, допустим чтобы решение подходило для тех случае когда высота и ширина картинок будет больше или меньше, и чтобы не зависело от количества изображений. в данном случае если изображений становится меньше или ширина с высотой у изображений будет больше, то данное решение не подойдет. Как сделать, чтобы был отступ между изображениями для других похожих блоков без создания дополнительных классов?

Answer (score 3):

Вот набросал: https://jsfiddle.net/g1fx8zxk/

Исходный код:

```css
.present {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.present>img {
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: #aaa 0 0 10px 2px;
  display: block;
}

.present>span {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}


/* Бонус: раскоментируйте для выравнивания по центру
    .centered {
        text-align: center;
    }*/
```

```html
<div class="centered">
  <div class="present">
    <img src="http://img.thrfun.com/img/075/082/large_willow_tree_ts1.jpg" />
    <span>Дерево</span>
  </div>
  <div class="present">
    <img src="http://img.thrfun.com/img/075/082/large_willow_tree_ts1.jpg" />
    <span>Дерево</span>
  </div>
</div>`
```

А теперь вопрос: неужели так сложно?

Comment: Скоро ребята будут скидывать ссылки на psd файлы с просьбой отверстать проект и поделиться ссылкой на гитхаб :)

Answer (score 1):

Используйте плюшки Флексбокса (CSS Flexible Box Layout Module). Вот тут оооочень скромный пример:

```css
.wrapp{display:flex}
.imagesBox{width:25%;text-align:center}
.imagesBox img{
    width:100%;
    border-radius:100px;width: 80%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapp">
    <div class="imagesBox">
        <img src="https://dreamgold.ua/image/catalog/lazyrite/souvenirs/3058.jpg">
        <p>НЕ ПИТЬ</p>
    </div>
    <div class="imagesBox">
        <img src="https://dreamgold.ua/image/catalog/lazyrite/souvenirs/3058_1.jpg">
        <p>ПИТЬ</p>
    </div> 
    <div class="imagesBox">
        <img src="https://dreamgold.ua/image/catalog/lazyrite/souvenirs/3058.jpg">
        <p>НЕ ПИТЬ</p>
    </div>
    <div class="imagesBox">
        <img src="https://dreamgold.ua/image/catalog/lazyrite/souvenirs/3058_1.jpg">
        <p>ПИТЬ</p>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Если ищите универсальные решения, смотрите в сторону css-фреймворков - bootstrap и там ещё много [читайте тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA).